# getting Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.ComponentResourceContainer not found. when using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am using jsf2.0 and spring 3.0.and  i integrated spring  context in my web.xml.when trying to  apply primeaces to my jSF pages  it is  showing as  mentioned above in the question. i included primefaces3.4 jar in WEB-INF/lib  and also put in class path.and added concerned name space in jsf page.  i am getting error as above. i have  put the WEB-INF/lib here

```
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar 
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
javaee.jar
jsf-api-2.0.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.0-b13.jar
ojdbc7.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
primefaces-3.4.jar
spring-2.5.jar
spring-jdbc.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

i am using myfaces  jsf2.o version.and  my jsf page login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head><link rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css"   href="/RealtimeApplication/CSS/styles.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title> Please Login</title>
</head>
<f:view>

<body>
<h:form>

<b> choose date</b><p:calendar value="#{login1.date}" mode="inline" id="inlineCal"/>            

   <br/>
```

please help me in accomplishing my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primefaces 3.4 needs jsf 2.1. you can see dependencies [here](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.4/primefaces-3.4.pom). update your version to 2.1 and try again.

Comment: can u suugest me  which cersion of prime faces  supported in  jsf2.0?

Comment: primefaces 3.1.1 supports jsf 2.0. see [primefaces-3.1.1.pom](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.1.1/primefaces-3.1.1.pom)

Comment: but I strongly advise that update your jsf version if it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces works with JSF 2.0, 2.1 and since PrimeFaces4.0 also with 2.2.

Could you please post the stacktrace? Please also use h:head instead of head.